# How to find a Guile package?

Tags: guile

I found a code example in the webs, that solves a current problem of mine by using the the *os process* module.

```
(use-modules (os process))
```

(http://gnu-guile.7481.n7.nabble.com/getting-pipes-going-td14625.html#a14627)

That's cool, except I don't have that module, and don't know where and how to get it.

Can you help?

(I use Guile 2.0, on Debian.)

Comment: I found this reference page that lists the pipe procedure http://www.nongnu.org/guile-lib/doc/ref/os.process/ if you click on the Guile Library header on top you will find a download link. Hope this is what you need.

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure that it is what you needed, that's why I didn't post as an answer. Now that we are sure, I have written a short answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module/library you are looking for is called "Guile Library" (guile-lib) and is [introduced here](http://www.nongnu.org/guile-lib/) (nongnu.org)

The function `run-with-pipe` is [documented here](http://www.nongnu.org/guile-lib/doc/ref/os.process/) and the library may be [downloaded here](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/guile-lib/).